# Pandas: How to query multi-level columns

Tags: python, select, pandas

Blet's take the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Region' : ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B'],
'Store' : ['A', ' B ', 'A ', 'B ', 'A ', 'A'],
'Quantity': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'Date' : ['2009-04-05','2009-04-05','2010-05-05', '2009-08-05', '2011-02-05', '2009-04-05']})
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
df.set_index(['Date','Region','Store'], inplace=True)
df_1 = df.unstack(level=[1,2])
```

Using the resulting DataFrame df_1 how can I find those dates where Stores A and B sold products in the same region products. As an answer to this question the query should return only the date '2009-04-05'

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to dig around the df_1.xs(...) to select the data you're interested in.

Comment: Hi, I already tried but the problem with that is that I need to have overlaps in the columns (i.e. both not None and >0), hence I am afraid that a xs query is not enough

Answer (score 0):

Why do you drop the indices? They contain useful information (that is, what you have grouped over to get your data - most likely you will need this when you want to do calculations based on the groupings :) )!

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: len(x)==2)
```

Gives me

```
Out[197]: 
Date        Region
2009-04-05  A          True
            B         False
2009-08-05  C         False
2010-05-05  C         False
2011-02-05  C         False
dtype: bool
```

You can think about a better condition than checking the length of the group (if you have an entry for `0` or `NaN` sells, this gets marginally more complicated - you'll have to filter x first) , but all we give you here is a starting point :)

Comment: Thanks FooBar, I really appreciate your help. But do you have an idea how to do that filtering with df_1. In my real world problem, I need to use the unstack df as there are more complicated comparisons necessary

Comment: You are purposefully losing information, how can that help at doing more complicated comparisons? In any case, you should do those computations on `df_1` but keep "the real" `df` with you, it contains way more information!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start with the unstacked dataframe `df_1`, I think you can do the following. I'm breaking it into several steps so that you can see what I'm doing. Of course you can chain many of the steps.

```
In [61]: df_2 = df_1.applymap(lambda x: 1 if pd.notnull (x) else 0)

In [62]: df_2
Out[62]: 
            Quantity             
Region             A      C     B
Store              A   B  A  B  A
Date                             
2009-04-05         1   1  0  0  1
2009-08-05         0   0  0  1  0
2010-05-05         0   0  1  0  0
2011-02-05         0   0  1  0  0

[4 rows x 5 columns]
In [63]: df_3 = df_2.sum(level=1,axis=1)

In [64]: df_3
Out[64]: 
Region      A  B  C
Date               
2009-04-05  2  1  0
2009-08-05  0  0  1
2010-05-05  0  0  1
2011-02-05  0  0  1

[4 rows x 3 columns]

In [65]: print df_3[df_3>=2].dropna(how='all').index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2009-04-05]
Length: 1, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```